# Creating Meteor App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm very new to this. I installed meteor successfully (it did ask for my user password, which I haven't seen in any tutorials).

Now when I try to enter "meteor create myApp", it says meteor: command not found. So obviously meteor isn't working on my computer, even though the installation appears to have been successful. Am I missing something/is there something else I need to install as well? I've never developed anything in my life, except HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to sort your permissions out.

Check to see if this works instead

```
sudo meteor create yourApp
```

If so, you need to reinstall meteor. Usually meteor tries to take care of this for you but something must have gone wrong. Try installing it again to see if it helps.

I'm not sure of this helps you run meteor without sudo, but it might at least let you use it. I'm not too pro on how to let the normal user use it.

Comment: In this case it is probably best to reinstall meteor, and this time anytime you use `sudo`, use `sudo -H` instead. The `-H` flag basically lets you own it in the end.